# Validates numbers with regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I would like to validates format of a decimal, which need to be like : 0 or 0.5 or 1 or 1.5 ...
Also, I must be able to accept "," or "." (for users of differents countries)

Could you help me please ? I'm not really good with regular expressions...

Thanks.

Comment: Will you be matching negative numbers?

Comment: In my model, I write this : `validates_format_of :default_duration, :with => /[0-9][0-9]*([.,][0-9][0-9]*)*/, :message => "Wrong format" `  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

Comment: No negative numbers, only integer or x and a half.

Comment: [Regular expression validator accept decimal numbers 0 or 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225931/regular-expression-validator-accept-decimal-numbers-0-or-5?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
 /^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/
```

`^` is start of the string

`$` is end of the string

`^`,`$` is essential else it would match anywhere in between..for example the above regex without ^,$ would also match `xyz344.66xyz`

`\d` matches a **single** digit

`+` is a **quantifier** that matches 1 to many **preceding** character or group..so \d+ means match 1 to many digits

`?` means match preceding character or group optionally that is  0 to 1 time

Comment: Thanks for the information. Which validator do you use ? I tried validates_format_of but it doesn't works...

Comment: @user2072365 [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456785/ruby-regexp-match-string-exactly) can help you...

Comment: I tried `if self.default_duration =~ /^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/` but I always have an error, even with just an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp could help:

```
 ^\d+[,\.]?\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^\d+((\.|\,)\d)?$/`

Matches `12`, `12,0`, `12.0`. If you wanted to add many trailing digits,
`/^\d+(\.|\,)?\d+$/`